# html_read: Read only data, not shape of table [A rows x B columns] (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table

I'm scraping data from a website using pd.read_html in a loop using `Python 3.7`, and struggle to export it.

Relevant part of the html string:

```
html_source =

<div class="reiterZwischenzeile">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<table class="tabelleOhneWidth" width="100%" cellspacing="0px">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="left" width="300px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="20px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="80px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="20px" valign="middle">
        <col class="left" width="20px" valign="middle">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="tabelleKopfUo left" colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            Teilarbeit
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfUo center" rowspan="2">
            Arbeitszeit-<br>bedarf
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfUo center" rowspan="2">
            Flächen-<br>leistung
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfUo center" colspan="5">
            Maschinenkosten
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfUo center" rowspan="2">
            Diesel-<br>bedarf
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOoUo center">
            Abschreibung
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOoUo center">
            Zinskosten
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOoUo center">
            Sonstiges&nbsp;<img src="images/info_white_10.png" border="none"> 
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOoUo center">
            Reparaturen
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOoUo center">
            Betriebsstoffe
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOo center" colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOo center">
            Akh/ha
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOo center">
            ha/h
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOo center" colspan="5">
            €/ha
        </td>
        <td class="tabelleKopfOo center" colspan="5">
            l/ha
        </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  left">
                2.000 l, Aufbaupflanzenschutzspritze; 138 kW
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                Feldarbeit
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                0.11
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                9.09
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                3.72
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                0.91
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                0.24
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                1.59
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                0.68
            </td>
            <td class="tabelleEbene2  right">
                0.90
            </td>
        </tr>



</tbody></table>
```

Then I read the html tables in every iteration like this:

```
        df_list = pd.read_html(html_source, skiprows = [0,1,2])
```

Printing df_list gives me this (indexing df_list[0] doesn't help either):

```
print(df_list)

[                                             0           1     2   ...  11  12  13
0  2.000 l, Aufbaupflanzenschutzspritze; 138 kW  Feldarbeit  0.11  ...            

[1 rows x 14 columns]]
```

I tried the same with a simple html code like this:

```
<html>

<body>


<table><tr></tr></table>
<table><tr></tr></table>


blablabal
blabalalb
slkjflsjbs
sjflsbsb


Table1
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>Test1</td><td>3</td><td>6</td><td>8.8</td><td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<td>4</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>88</td><td>Test</td>
<td>74</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>88</td><td>Test</td><td>74</td><td>77</td><td>78</td><td>88</td><td>Test</td>
</table>


</body>

<html>
```

```
htmlname = r"example.html"
html = open(htmlname, 'r')

source_code = html.read()
#print(source_code)
tables = pd.read_html(source_code, skiprows=[1])

print(tables)

[       0  1  2    3     4
0  Test1  3  6  8.8  Test]
>>>
```

Why do I get this shape description when I read in from the website and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: you can try to access each table data by looping over `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: But what is causing the different results in the example data and the website code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this option:-

```
pd.options.display.show_dimensions = False
df_list = pd.read_html(html_source,skiprows=3)
print(df_list)
```

Also just to answer why does it show dimension for the first html source is that
with pandas newer versions the dimensions are not shown for small dataframes where they fit console. They are only shown when the dataframe output is large. Example:- In your case

```
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df1 = df[df.columns[range(4)]]
df1
```

If you pick only 4 column from df_list it will not show dimension due to the lesser number of columns 4 as compared to 14.